# error: invalid use of non-static data member c++

Tags: c++

**list.hpp**

```
template <typename Data>
class List{

   private:

     struct Node* Head;

   protected:

     using LinearContainer<Data>::size;

   struct Node
   {

      Data Elements;
      Node* Nxt;

      // Specific constructors
      Node(Data);

   };

   public:

   List() = default;
}
```

**list.cpp**

```
template<typename Data>
List<Data>::Node::Node(Data Elemento) {

    List<Data>::Head.Elements = Elemento;
    size = 1;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Head'
    List<Data>::Head.Elements = Elemento;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
1 error generated.
```

What’s my mistake, can you please tell me? I have not put the "main" as I know for certain that it has nothing to do while "size" is inherited from a higher class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid use of non-static Data Member c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204551/invalid-use-of-non-static-data-member-c)

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. `Elements = Elemento;` is what you need.

Comment: `size` is not a member of `Node`, and `using LinearContainer<Data>::size;` seems very out of place. I would recommend that you review the fundamentals before you dive into templates.